# Node-Red detect dashboard page visit

Tags: user-interface, dashboard, node-red

How can I get `node-red` to detect that the `dashboard UI` page has been visited, i.e. someone is looking at the page.

I say this be cause I would then send more frequent updates to the dashboard then when no one is visiting. i know i can implement a Websockets, but then this will be a page that i create not the `dashboard UI`

> I have looked everywhere, and in forums, no solutions offered besides
>   create a custom webpage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ui_control` node can be used to emit messages when this happens.

From the info sidebar for the `ui_control` node:

> When any browser client connects or loses connection, or changes tab, this node will emit a `msg` containing:
>
> - `payload` - connect, lost, or change.
> - `socketid` - the ID of the socket (this will change every time the browser reloads the page).
> - `socketip` - the ip address from where the connection originated.
> - `tab` - the number of the tab. (Only for 'change' event).
> - `name` - the name of the tab. (Only for 'change' event).